# What is the best way to get a colour property via Xamarin UITests

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to write some automated tests for an app we have created for iOS and Android.

The app is written with Xamarin.

The app at some point changes the background colour of a box depending on a value of an integer.

I want to write an automated test that checks this colour is displayed correctly in the app. 
This will involve getting the colour of the box and comparing it with what we have stored (hard-coded)

[image]

I added an automationID tag of "visit_thresholdColor" to the object I would like to get the colour of but I am unsure on what method to take to grab this.

I have seen things like this

app.Query(x => x.Marked("visit_thresholdColor").Invoke("getBackground").Invoke("getColor"))

but this does not work and throws this

[image]

Here is a picture of the app, I am trying to grab the green and yellow properties.

[image]

Comment: Can you found finally how to do that? I have the same problem so I appreciate any information you can provide me

Comment: @DavidLópez Unfortunately I did not find a way of doing this, I just wrote tests that checked the text displayed as expected in the end. We have now moved away from Xamarin.